# exemplo de login com Basic Athentication para swift?

Tags: swift

Olá.
tenho uma api em cakephp com basic Authentication, para o android foi fácil mas não estou conseguindo um exemplo de requisição "POST" passando como parâmetro o "user" e "password" via http:

se alguém tiver um exemplo, agradeço.

Comment: Olá Bruno, bem vindo ao StackOverflow, poderia nos postar um trecho do código ou um cenário onde sua pergunta se aplique? Fica mais fácil para que a comunidade possa lhe ajudar com seu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talvez esta resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24380884/1518921)

Swift 3:

```
let username = "usuario"
let password = "senha"

let loginString = String(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
let loginData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString()

//Cria uma requisição
let url = URL(string: "http://www.example.com/pagina")
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

// executa
let urlConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)
```

Em Swift 2 com `NSMutableURLRequest`:

```
let username = "usuario"
let password = "senha"

let loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
let loginData: NSData = loginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])

//Cria uma requisição
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com/pagina")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

// Executa
let urlConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)
```